# One side annotated with OneToOne and the other with OneToMany annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-many, one-to-one

At first I thought it was a mistake but then I found this very odd situation in several other tutorials on the net. I don't understand how this works.

User bean:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="users")  
public class User {  

@Id  
@GeneratedValue  
private Integer id;  

private String login;  

private String password;  

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",  
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}  
)  
private Role role;
```

Role bean:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="roles")  
public class Role { 

@Id  
@GeneratedValue  
private Integer id;  

private String role;  

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",   
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},  
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}  
)  
private Set<user> userRoles;
```

Can someone please explain how this works? And why do it like this?

Comment: It doesn't, and you shouldn't do it like this. You should have a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne instead. I don't see why you would like a join table, and not simply a foreign key in the user table, either.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but after seeing it in several places I started to think there might be a good reason that I just don't know about. Thank you very much for clearing this up. If you put in an answer, I'll accept it.